# IF in MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column named "image_path" in a table "tb_users". I have saved the image name for users who are not from facebook and image path who are registered from facebook like as shown below :

```
**image_path**
https://graph.facebook.com/100916463/picture
user1.png
user2.png
```

Now I want to concat the base path in "select query" for those users whose "image_path" doesn't contain http else return as it is.

For e.g if image_path is `https://graph.facebook.com/100916463/picture`, and it contains `http` then it should be returned by select query as it is but if `image_path` is `user1.png` then `concat` a basepath like `http://www.example.com/images/` so that select query should return `http://www.example.com/images/user1.png`.
?
How can I do this with a single select query using IF ? OR any other operator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a case and  LIKE you can achieve what you want ...

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN image_path LIKE 'http%' THEN 'something' ELSE 'somethingelse' END
```

Comment: `LIKE` will perform worse than `SUBSTR` or `LEFT` for this problem.

Comment: @aleroot - Not really, null and empty strings are a different case.  `LIKE` will clump them in with the local-site case and will return a bad image path.

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT IF(SUBSTR(image_path, 0, 7) == "http://" OR SUBSTR(image_path, 0, 8) == "https://", image_path, CONCAT("http://www.example.com/images/", image_path)) FROM ...
```

Comment: What happens if image path is null or empty ?

Comment: @aleroot, it should be handled separately if you use this solution, agreed

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution would handle `null` and empty-string values (using a default image in their place), and would use `LEFT` for optimal performance.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN `image_path` IS NULL OR `image_path` = '' 
            THEN 'http://www.example.com/default.jpg'
        WHEN LEFT(`image_path`, 4) = 'http' 
            THEN `image_path`
        ELSE CONCAT('http://www.example.com/images/', `image_path`)
    END AS `image_path`
FROM `your_table`
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more direct, and would allow for additional cases if/when you need to add functionality to your application, if you coded the type of image_path when you store it. Change your data structure to:

```
image_path_type_id int,
image_path varchar(250),
```

and make image_path_type_id point to a table with the possible image types. Then your logic can be deterministic, it will expand easily for other image types and/or conditions, and it won't break if there's a typo in your image_path (well, the logic won't break).

Your select becomes:

```
select case 
    when image_path_type_id = 1
    then image_path
    when image_path_type_id = 2
    then concat('http://staticpath', image_path
end
```

Adding another case won't require a change to the schema; you would just add another line to the list of types in the type table.

Comment: That is also a good idea. I already thought of this idea. But I already had a lot of results so I won't wish to update type_id for them. Anyways, Thanks a lot.